# Obtener ruta para guardar archivos o fotos en JAVA

Tags: java, upload

Utilizo el siguiente fragmento de código para obtener la ruta relativa del proyecto y "almacenar" la foto en dicho directorio.

```
String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "/pasta/fotos";
```

Pero al momento de darle clean and build me elimina los archivos alojados ahí. Que solución para obtener el classpath y que se aloje realmente el archivo podría utilizar?

Answer (score 0):

para obtener la ruta del proyecto puedes utilizar un File de la siguiente manera:
`File proyecto = new File(".");`
Si queres apuntar a algun archivo en particular dentro de ese directorio podes usar el constructor con dos parametros:
`File proyecyo = new File(".", "archivo.ext");`

Answer (score 0):

Puede utilizar las clases Path y Paths, para trabajar con un directorio externo:

```
Path pathAlDirectorio = Paths.get("c:","pasta","fotos","miFoto.png");

String pathComoString = pathAlDirectorio.toString();
File pathComoFile = pathAlDirectorio.toFile();
```